# Artifacts in DensityPlot for Mathematica 8.0?

Tags: plotting

I am using the following code in *Mathematica 8.0*

```
DensityPlot[Sin[5 x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The plot should clearly be independent of y, but the result I am getting is

[image]

Is there any way to fix this with this version of *Mathematica*? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: just add `PlotPoints -> 50` - the resolution isn't high enough by default.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the default number of points been a small number (as pointed out by @Jens).
You can define the number of points using [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) or let *Mathematica* decide by itself where more points are needed by allowing a larger [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html). I favour the later.

```
DensityPlot[
 Sin[5 x]
 , {x, -10, 10}
 , {y, -10, 10}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , MaxRecursion -> 5
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: ...and you can even set both `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` if you're feeling adventurous. ;)